# How do I know my aap_d, app_code for my HERE Freemium account?

Tags: rest, api, routes

I want to use HERE Routing REST API. The URL below

```
https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/getroute.xml?app_id=
{YOUR_APP_ID}&app_code={YOUR_APP_CODE}
&routeId=YOUR_ROUTE_ID>&mode=fastest;car&maneuverattributes=position,link
&linkattributes=shape,DynamicSpeedInfo&requestid=<YOUR_TRACKING_ID>
```

requires attributes like "app_code", "app_id" etc. How do I know about them? I did not get them in email when I signed-up for HERE Freemium account.

Comment: Hi @Manoj and welcome to slack. If, you find afterwards that there is a typo in your question, please don't add the new info in a comment, edit your question instead.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. One may have to navigate to https://developer.here.com/projects
From this page select the project from the table given below. For Freemium account there should be only one project. Click on the project Name.
One  may see "Get your credentials:". That's it.